# How to create a SQL file in PowerShell and save the file to a specified drive. The sql file just needs to be a basic boiler plate

Tags: sql, powershell, automation, scripting

I am trying to create a SQL file with PowerShell that saves to a specified drive, but I am having issues with the creation of the SQL file. It just needs to be a basic boiler plate for the file.

I tried:

```
#Generate SQL File with Server and Customer Name
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO') | out-null 

$s = new-object ('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server') "LOCALHOST\SQL#"  

$dbs=$s.Databases 

$dbs["Customer Name"].Script() 

#Show Available Drives
Get-PSDrive

#Output the SQL file to specified drive
$dbs["Customer Name"].Script() | Out-File D:\PSScripts\(Customer Name).SQL 
$dbs["Northwind"].Script()
```

But this code throws this error:

> Exception calling "Script" with "0" argument(s): "Script failed for Database 'Northwind'. "
> At line:1 char:25
>
> - $dbs["Northwind"].Script <<<< ()
> - CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
> - FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException

I have even just tried to save a file with just a `.SQL` extension with SQL, but this is not what I want.

Comment: Please [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: The error is unrelated to saving to a file. The ` $dbs["Customer Name"].Script()` method call itself fails.